# List + Dictionary comprehension key filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

With the following example schema:

```
test_dict = {
    '2015': {
        'bar1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar2': [2, 2, 2, 2],
        'bar3': [4, 3, 2, 1]
    },
    '2016': {
        'bar1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar2': [5, 5, 5, 5],
        'bar3': [4, 3, 2, 1]
    },
    '2017': {
        'bar1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar2': [4, 4, 4, 4],
        'bar3': [4, 3, 2, 1]
    }
}
```

I need to gather all the lists specified by the 2nd dict key. So I currently have the code:

```
await asyncio.gather(*[get_matches(browser, ser) for ser in test_dict['2015']['bar2']])
```

but I want to gather all the lists that belong to each `bar2` key meaning I want to comprehend into `gather()`: `

```
test_dict['2015']['bar2']
test_dict['2016']['bar2']
test_dict['2017']['bar2']
```

by specifying `bar2` so that `gather()` will receive:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

how can I?

I tried doing it like this but didn't work:

```
{k2:v2 for k2,v2 in {k:v for k,v in test.items()}.items() if k2 == 'bar2' }
```

not to mention gather will want a dict in the end.

Comment: so you want an object you can access like `output[[5,5,5,5]]` ? or just `output['2015'] # [5,5,5,5]`

Comment: first write it using normal for-loop - and later convert it to list/dict comprehension. It will need two `for`-loops.

Comment: do you need `gather('browser', 2), gather('browser', 2), ...` or `gather('browser', [2, 2, 2, 2]), gather('browser', [5, 5, 5, 5]), ...` ?

Comment: Edited with more info and attempt

Comment: Can you please remove the asyncio part? It makes more difficult to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need

```
get_matches(browser, [2, 2, 2, 2]), get_matches(browser, [5, 5, 5, 5]), ...
```

then

```
[ get_matches(browser, v['bar2']) for k, v in test_dict.items() ]
```

If you need

```
get_matches(browser, 2), get_matches(browser, 2), ...
```

then

```
[ get_matches(browser, ser) for k, v in test_dict.items() for ser in v['bar2'] ]
```

If you need only list

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

then

```
[ v['bar2'] for k, v in test_dict.items() ]
```

or even

```
[ v['bar2'] for v in test_dict.values() ]
```

---

Minimal working code

```
test_dict = {
    '2015': {
        'bar1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar2': [2, 2, 2, 2],
        'bar3': [4, 3, 2, 1]
    },
    '2016': {
        'bar1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar2': [5, 5, 5, 5],
        'bar3': [4, 3, 2, 1]
    },
    '2017': {
        'bar1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar2': [4, 4, 4, 4],
        'bar3': [4, 3, 2, 1]
    }
}


print([('browser', v['bar2']) for k, v in test_dict.items()])
print('---')
print([('browser', ser) for k, v in test_dict.items() for ser in v['bar2']])
print('---')
print([ v['bar2'] for k, v in test_dict.items() ])
print([ v['bar2'] for v in test_dict.values() ])
```

Result:

```
[('browser', [2, 2, 2, 2]), ('browser', [5, 5, 5, 5]), ('browser', [4, 4, 4, 4])]
---
[('browser', 2), ('browser', 2), ('browser', 2), ('browser', 2), ('browser', 5), ('browser', 5), ('browser', 5), ('browser', 5), ('browser', 4), ('browser', 4), ('browser', 4), ('browser', 4)]
---
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: The 2nd one is best for `asyncio.gather()`. I hadn't thought of just going with another `for` to the right. Thanks.